# How does the CRC32 function work when using sampling data?

Tags: python, hash, hex

I would like to ask you about explanation of the following short function in Python..

```
from zlib import crc32

def test_set_check(identifier, test_ratio):
    return crc32(np.int64(identifier)) & 0xffffffff < test_ratio * 2**32
```

The above-mentioned function should be the same as the following function:

```
import hashlib

def test_set_check(identifier, test_ratio, hash=hashlib.md5):
    return hash(np.int64(identifier)).digest()[-1] < 256 * test_ratio
```

Both functions should be used for data sampling (select some rows in a table). For example, if `test_ratio` is 0.2 then it means that I want to sample 20% data, the value is lower or equal to 51 (~20% of 256). I understand how the second function works but I don't understand the first one. Could you please explain to me the first function? I don't understand the following part: `crc32(np.int64(identifier)) & 0xffffffff < test_ratio * 2**32`

Answer (score 19):

The `crc32` function outputs an unsigned 32-bit number, and the code tests if the CRC value is lower than the test_ratio times the maximum 32-bit number.

The `& 0xffffffff` mask is there only to [ensure compatibility with Python 2 and 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html#zlib.crc32). In Python 2 the same function could return a *signed* integer, in a range from -(2^31) to (2^31) - 1, masking this with the `0xffffffff` mask normalises the value to a signed.

So basically, either version turns the identifier into an integer, and the hash is used to make that integer reasonably uniformly distributed in a range; for the MD5 hash that's the last byte making the value fall between 0 and 255, for the CRC32 checksum the value lies between 0 and (2^32)-1. This integer is then compared to the full range; if it falls below the `test_ratio * maximum` cut-off point it is considered selected.

You could also use a random function, but then you'd get a different subset of your input each time you picked a sample; by hashing the identifier you get to produce a *consistent* subset. The difference between the two methods is that they'll produce a different subset, so you could use both together to pick multiple, independent subsets from the same input.

Compare:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from zlib import crc32
>>> from hashlib import md5
>>> import random
>>> identifier = np.int64(random.randrange(2**63))
>>> md5(identifier).digest()[-1]
243
>>> md5(identifier).digest()[-1] / 256  # as a ratio of the full range
0.94921875
>>> crc32(identifier)
4276259108
>>> crc32(identifier) / (2 ** 32)   # ratio again
0.9956441605463624
>>> identifier = np.int64(random.randrange(2**63))  # different id to compare
>>> md5(identifier).digest()[-1] / 256  # as a ratio of the full range
0.83203125
>>> crc32(identifier) / (2 ** 32)   # ratio again
0.10733163682743907
```

So the two different methods produce different outputs, but as long as the CRC32 and MD5 hashes produce reasonably *uniformly distributed* hash values, then either will give you a fair 20% sampling rate.